# I can not get my do while loop to work in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

Here is my code. I am trying to get it to ask 1. "What would you like to eat" and then 2. ask again if userEntree is not burger, chicken, or fish.

```
var userEntree = prompt('What entree would you like?')

do {
   var userEntree = prompt('What entree would you like?')
}
while(userEntree.toLowerCase() != "burger" || 
      userEntree.toLowerCase() != "chicken" || userEntree.toLowerCase() != 
      "fish")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong operator:

`(userEntree.toLowerCase() != "burger" && userEntree.toLowerCase() != "chicken" && userEntree.toLowerCase() != "fish")`

"Do something **until** the user's answer is chicken **or** burger **or** fish" translates into a while-condition as "Do something **while** the answer is **not** chicken **and not** burger **and not** fish."

Also, the first `var userEntree = prompt('What entree would you like?')` is unnecessary; this way, the code will always prompt at least twice. You should either declare `userEntree` as `null`, or write the loop as a `while` loop instead of `do-while`.